# how to find the resource code according to a contract address like using etherscan on eth?

Tags: nearprotocol

how to find the resource code according to a contract address like using etherscan on eth?

for example:

this is my hash for staking near to a validator node:
https://explorer.near.org/transactions/3fmNUWvrTnbySNo3eycPnuT7Fn5mR8LzcUJkdX1Y5xJd

I was using the 'deposit_and_stake' method to realize that, but how to get the code of the method in the contract?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to match the deployed contract back to the source code. To do that we would need to have:

1. some registry of contract hashes mapping those to the source code links (could be a contract on chain)
2. tooling that would automatically push the data into the registry
3. the source code of the contract should be open-source and have reproducible  builds setup (e.g. publish a Docker image with all the dependencies, so re-compilation of the same source code will produce a completely identical Wasm binary)

DevConsole will strike to provide better tooling for this scenario, but it is not there yet.